# Can the procedure of VM IRQ injection in KVM be parallel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtualization, qemu, kvm

When I have many IRQs to inject into many individual VMs, can I make the procedure of injection be parallel?

I found this part is the bottleneck of my project, so I want to optimize it.

Any idea about how I could achieve this?

Comment: Are you writing a kernel module or an userspace hypervisor? What are you doing right now to inject IRQs and what did you try, if anything? An example scenario of what you are looking for would also be useful.

Comment: I'm writing a kernel module. The expected scenario is many VMs are triggered at the same time, in the current implementation, VM is triggered one by one, when there is no logical relation between the VMs.